# Custom filter with dropdown in ag-grid is not working in angular 10

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have created a Grid with **ag-grid** in my angular application. There is a column which name is Category. The rows of this column can only contain A or B or C value. Now I want to create a custom filter with dropdown containing A,B and C value. The code is given below:

**Component HTML:**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="currentValue" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged()" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

**Component TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AgFrameworkComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { FilterChangedEvent, IAfterGuiAttachedParams, IFloatingFilter, IFloatingFilterParams, TextFilterModel } from 'ag-grid-community';

export interface SelectFloatingFilterParams extends IFloatingFilterParams {
  selectedValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-floating-filter',
})
export class CategoryFloatingFilterComponent implements IFloatingFilter, AgFrameworkComponent<SelectFloatingFilterParams> {
  params: SelectFloatingFilterParams;
  currentValue: string;

  agInit(params: SelectFloatingFilterParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.currentValue = this.params.selectedValue;
  }

  valueChanged() {
    let valueToUse = this.currentValue === '' ? null : this.currentValue;
    this.params.parentFilterInstance((instance: TextFilterModel) =>
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', valueToUse === '' ? null : valueToUse));
  }

  onParentModelChanged(parentModel: TextFilterModel): void {
    if (!parentModel) {
      this.currentValue = "";
    }
    else {
      this.currentValue = parentModel.filter;
    }
  }
}
```

But during compiling time I am getting error which is given below:

> Property 'onFloatingFilterChanged' does not exist on type
> 'TextFilterModel'.
>
> 24       instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', valueToUse === ''
> ? null : valueToUse));

It means **onFloatingFilterChanged** does not exist in **TextFilterModel** class. So how I can filter the grid after choosing a value from dropdown. Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my answer. the code is given below:

```
agInit(params: SelectFloatingFilterParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.currentValue = this.params.selectedValue;
  }

  valueChanged() {
    let valueToUse = this.currentValue === '' ? null : this.currentValue;
    this.params.parentFilterInstance((instance: TextFilter) =>
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', valueToUse === '' ? null : valueToUse));
  }

  onParentModelChanged(parentModel: TextFilterModel): void {
    if (!parentModel) {
      this.currentValue = "";
    }
    else {
      this.currentValue = parentModel.filter;
    }
```